# How do I put two tables next to each other

Tags: tables, errors, code, error-bars

I've tried to use `\quad` and `\subfloat` but I'm still struggling to make it work.
Below is the code that I wrote.

```
\begin{table}[h!]
    \ centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
\textbf{Dimer profile} & \textbf{CP} \\
\hline
Monomer & 14.1 \\
\hline
Dimers  &  85.9 \\
\hline
Homodimers & 61.2 \\
\hline
Heterodimers & 24.6 \\
\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Sample 1: ApoE dimer profile (\%)}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
\textbf{Dimer profile} & \textbf{CP} & \textbf{CM} \\
\hline
Monomer & 59.8 & 1 \\
\hline
Dimers & 40.2 & 99 \\
\hline
Homodimers & 9.6 & 99 \\
\hline
Heterodimers& 30.6 & 0 \\
\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Sample 2: ApoE dimer profile (\%)}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. No `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}`. Please make a full example.

Comment: There is a space in `\ centering` that should not be there. For more information add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 1):

This may help.

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \begin{document}
 
\begin{tabular}{lr}
Sample 1: ApoE dimer profile (\%)  &  Sample 2: ApoE dimer profile (\%)\\
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Dimer profile} & \textbf{CP} \\
\hline
Monomer & 14.1 \\
\hline
Dimers  &  85.9 \\
\hline
Homodimers & 61.2 \\
\hline
Heterodimers & 24.6 \\
\hline
\end{tabular} \label{tab:my_label}
&
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Dimer profile} & \textbf{CP} & \textbf{CM} \\
\hline
Monomer & 59.8 & 1 \\
\hline
Dimers & 40.2 & 99 \\
\hline
Homodimers & 9.6 & 99 \\
\hline
Heterodimers& 30.6 & 0 \\
\hline
\end{tabular} \label{tab:my_label1}\\
\end{tabular}


 \end{document}
```

The output is:
[image]

**EDIT:**
Here is your code. Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lr}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Dimer profile} & \textbf{CP} \\
\hline
Monomer & 14.1 \\
\hline
Dimers  &  85.9 \\
\hline
Homodimers & 61.2 \\
\hline
Heterodimers & 24.6 \\
\hline
\end{tabular} \label{tab:my_label}
&
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Dimer profile} & \textbf{CP} & \textbf{CM} \\
\hline
Monomer & 59.8 & 1 \\
\hline
Dimers & 40.2 & 99 \\
\hline
Homodimers & 9.6 & 99 \\
\hline
Heterodimers& 30.6 & 0 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}\label{tab:my_label}\\
Sample 2: ApoE dimer profile (\%) & Sample 1: ApoE dimer profile (\%)
\end{tabular}

 \end{document}
```

This will look like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Looks amazing!!!

Comment: However, how do I add captions to each table?

Comment: @Gaussian123 your captions are there after `\begin{tabular}{lr}`

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Add the captions under each table?

Comment: @Gaussian123 Please have a look at the edited answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it with the `floatrow` package:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{floatrow}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{floatrow}
        \centering
    \ttabbox{ \caption{Sample 1: ApoE dimer profile (\%)} \label{tab:my_label}}%
    {\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
    \textbf{Dimer profile} & \textbf{CP} \\
    \hline
    Monomer & 14.1 \\
    \hline
    Dimers & 85.9 \\
    \hline
    Homodimers & 61.2 \\
    \hline
    Heterodimers & 24.6 \\
    \hline
        \end{tabular}}
    \qquad
    \ttabbox{ \caption{Sample 2: ApoE dimer profile (\%)} \label{tab:my_label}}%
    {\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
    \textbf{Dimer profile} & \textbf{CP} & \textbf{CM} \\
    \hline
    Monomer & 59.8 & 1 \\
    \hline
    Dimers & 40.2 & 99 \\
    \hline
    Homodimers & 9.6 & 99 \\
    \hline
    Heterodimers& 30.6 & 0 \\
    \hline
        \end{tabular}}
        \end{floatrow}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do I put the caption under the tables no above?

Comment: I think the floatrow documentation explains  how to do it. However, be aware the typographical tradition  puts table captions *above* tables (the reason for tjhis comes from long tables, spreading over several pages).

Comment: To have the caption below the table, you can write `\floatsetup[table]{capposition=bottom}`. The default is `top`, and you also can choose `capposition=beside`.

Comment: Where must I add ```\floatsetup[table]{capposition=bottom}```

Comment: @Gaussian123:  The simplest is to add it just after `\begin{table}`. You also may ad it in the preamble, after the floatrow loading.